# How do I find next space in a C array?

Tags: c, arrays

I've got a question about array initialization/usage in C for storing `struct`s.

Suppose I have a Person `struct`:

```
struct person { 
  char *name;
  int age;
};
```

and I declare an array of `person struct`s:

```
struct person people[1000];
```

My question is, given this array at some future point in the program where `n` `struct person`s have been added to `people[]`, what is the correct way to tell where to put the `n + 1`th `struct person`?

In something like Java a `for` loop with `if(people[i] == null)` could tell you if that index was not yet holding any value, but in C because this is an array of actual values I know I can't check `if(people[i] == NULL)` since `NULL` is pointer.

Is there a reliable/correct way to do this in C?

Comment: The array contains 1000 `person` objects from the outset. There are no spaces left to fill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple solutions:

1. Just store the value of `n` and update it when necessary.
2. Allocate the items of the `people` array on the HEAP, so the type of the items will be `person*`. Then you can check for `null` pointers and it is also more memory friendly, as you do not have to store unnecessary elements. However, for computation performance, I would still not recommend to find the first empty array element with a a linear search, instead store the index of the first free item.

Comment: The one, who downvoted my answer: please leave a comment to let me known why do you think it is a bad answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a variable to keep track of number of elements in the array.

```
int people_count = 0;
struct person people[1000];

void add(struct person p) {
    people[people_count] = ...
    people_count++;
}
```

Comment: The number of elements in the array is 1000.

Answer (score 2):

In C, arrays cannot have positions that are empty, meaning that all the elements in an array must exist (in Java, you would essentially have array of pointers, whereas in C you have array of values of the size depending on your struct size).

One common solution would be to add `id` field to your struct that would indicate whether your struct on a particular position of the array has been initialized or not, i.e.:

```
struct person { 
  char *name;
  int age;
  int id; // meaning: is initialized
};
```

I am assuming you would like to put something in your array not only at the end (in this case the other answers are better) but also is some positions that haven't been initialized for some reason.